# How to keep form data after validation fail and when the page redirects with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have this form that I'm working with off a tutorial.  I'm trying keep the fields populated when there is a validation error.

Here is my form:

```
<div class="add">

<?php $errors4 = errors_seesion_funtion(); ?>
<?php echo form_errors($errors4); ?>
<div class="error-message"><?php echo message(); ?></div>

    <div class="done"><a href="../manage-employee-qsps.php"><input name="Done" type="button" value="Done" /></a></div>

    <h2>ADD New Department:</h2>

<form action="create-department-process.php" method="post">
      <p class="department-name">Department name:
        <input type="text" name="department_name" id="department-name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['department_name'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['department_name']); } ?>" />
      <span class="error">* <?php if (!empty($errors4)) { echo "<div class=\"error\">";
          echo "Hi";
          echo "</div>";
      }

      ?></span>

      </p>

      <p class="department-name">Test name:
        <input type="text" name="test_name" id="test-name" value="" />
      <span class="error">* <?php /*echo form_errors($errors4); */
      if (!empty($errors4)) {
          echo "<div class=\"error\">";
          echo "test name";
          echo "</div>";
      }

      ?></span>

      </p>

      <input type="submit" name="dept_added" id="add-btn" value="ADD Department" />
    </form>
<br />

<div class="cancel"><a href="../manage-employee-qsps.php">Cancel</a></div>
```

Here is my Session:

```
session_start();

function message() {
    if (isset($_SESSION["message"])) {
        $output = "<div class='message'>";
        $output .= htmlentities($_SESSION["message"]);
        $output .= "</div>";

        // clear message after use
        $_SESSION["message"] = null;

        return $output;
    }
}

function errors_seesion_funtion() {
    if (isset($_SESSION["errors3"])) {
        $errors2 = $_SESSION["errors3"];
        $_SESSION['post_data'] = $_POST;
        // clear message after use
        $_SESSION["errors3"] = null;

        return $errors2;
    }
}
```

Here is my Validation Functions:

```
$errors_array = array();

function fieldname_as_text($fieldname) {
  $fieldname = str_replace("_", " ", $fieldname);
  $fieldname = ucfirst($fieldname);
  return $fieldname;
}

function has_presence($value) {
    return isset($value) && $value !== "";
}

function validate_presences($required_fields) {
  global $errors6;
  foreach($required_fields as $field) {
    $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
    if (!has_presence($value)) {
        $errors6[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my create-department-process.php

```
if (isset($_POST['dept_added'])) {

$department_name = mysql_prep($_POST["department_name"]);

//Validations for form
$required_fields = array("department_name", "test_name");

validate_presences($required_fields);

if (!empty($errors6)) {
    $_SESSION["errors3"] = $errors6;
    redirect_to("add-department.php"); //this is the page the form is on
}

// Process the form

$query1  = "INSERT INTO departments (";
$query1 .= "  department_name ";
$query1 .= ") VALUES ( ";
$query1 .= "  '{$department_name}' ";
$query1 .= ") ";
$result1 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query1);

if ($result1) {
    // Success
    $_SESSION["message"] = "Department created.";   
    redirect_to("add-department.php");
} else {
    // Failure
    $_SESSION["message"] = "Department creation failed.";
    redirect_to("creation-error.php");
}

} else {
redirect_to("fail.php");
}
```

I've tried to put this in the value of my form

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['department_name'])) { echo      htmlentities($_POST['department_name']); } ?>
```

But the value I type in doesn't stay when PHP runs the form validation and redirects.  Does anyone have any idea on how I can keep the data I type into the form fields when I have a validation error?

Thank you for your time and Help!  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think your POST data is getting lost when you do this:

```
if (!empty($errors6)) {
    $_SESSION["errors3"] = $errors6;
    redirect_to("add-department.php"); //this is the page the form is on
}
```

I'm guessing `redirect_to` actually redirects your browser to the specified page, therefore resetting the REQUEST values and losing the pervious POST data. You either need to save the POST values in the session (a la `errors_seesion_funtion`) and access them from there in your form, or `include` the form above to preserve the original POST values.